# how to get runningvalue() in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2013, rdlc

I use RDLC reports in past but now i am using Crystal report. i use this formula in RDLC report

```
=Previous(RunningValue(Fields!balance.Value,sum,nothing))+Fields!balance.Value
```

but not find Running value in Crystal report. can anyone tell me where is it in crystal report? if not any other solution to do this?

i want result like this in balance column

```
id    name         debit     credit    balance
1     umer         100         0         100
2     umer          0         50          50
3     umer          0         10          40
4     umer          200        0         240
```

Comment: You mean `running total`?

Comment: no running total will be the total of whole data i want row1 balance in row2 and then row 2 balance in row3 and so on....

Comment: can you show with an example?

Comment: ok... here I can see `row2=row1-row2`... and `row3=row2-row3` but when it comes to row 4 it is `row4=row4+row3`... why there is difference in calculation? or my understanding is wrong?

Comment: the formula is balance = debit- credit, and i am getting row2 balance =  row1 balance + row2 debit - row2 credit.

Comment: This sure looks like a Running Total to me. The "balance" is the running total of additions of debit and subtractions of credit.

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in `Balance`

```
Whileprintingrecords;
Shared Numbervar balance;
Shared Numbervar display;

balance:=debit-credit;
display:=display+balance;
display
```

Comment: Local variables don't carry from row to row... This won't work unless the `display` variable is global (and you also don't need the `balance` variable). You're also missing the `whileprintingrecords` keyword to ensure this is evaluated in sorted record order.

Comment: Actually I have tested with `Shared` but somehow changed to local and it is working without `whileprintingrecords` I was able to see correct output.

Comment: Tested the solution prior posting the solution here but tested with `Shared`.

Comment: Just because it worked for your test case doesn't mean it'll work for ALL cases. The `whileprintingrecords` keyword forces the formula to evaluate after the records have been sorted, otherwise they will be evaluated in "original order" as CR puts it, which is not always predictable.

Comment: Why would you choose to let your solution have an error in it versus making a one-word change that would fix it?? To each his own, I guess.

Comment: If I feel that my solution has error or I am unable to give a solution I myself don't try to give solution at all.... Since I give a solution after working at my end I don't want to change... also I don't want to see myself in confusion state... will try your suggestion tomorrow and will update if it works.. Anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: An easy way to see this solution break down is to simply sort the report by any field other than the original sort. Your line-by-line balance will be all over the place and won't be in strict ascending order. As for my experience with CR, all I'll say is that it is more years than I care to think about.

Comment: Will surely try tomorrow... thanks for making me learn new things. I am just a beginner with just over a couple of years...by trying to provide solution in SO learning new things everyday.

Comment: @Ryan...I have sorted in `specified order` and checked my formula... I didn't get any wrong data... also tried by implementing `whileprintingrecords` also didn't get any wrong data.

Comment: Here's a [simple example](http://i.imgur.com/cvzpnnw.png) using SAP's own "Xtreme" database. The third column without the `whileprintingrecords` keyword doesn't work while the fourth column that uses `whileprintingrecords` accumulates correctly. That's the best proof I can give; if you still don't believe it then you're on your own.

Comment: @Ryan..no sir no issue of believing. I respect your advice I just gave my results....

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use a Running Total for this as this type of calculation is exactly what they're intended to be used for.

First, create a formula that will handle the debits as addition to the total and credits as subtractions: `{table.debitAmount} - {table.creditAmount}`

Then create a Running Total and plug the formula you just created into the "Field to summarize". In the "Evaluate" section of the Running Total screen, keep it set to "For each record" and in the "Reset" section, keep it set to "Never" if you want this balance to work over the entire report or pick a group if your balance should be by a grouping level.

EDIT: It goes without saying, but you'll want to verify that the "Type of summary" to be set to "Sum"